# How to change the settings for adding java class for Android studio

Tags: android

Hi i recently downloaded the new version of android studio. How can i change back the adding of java class to the old style. I will like to add superclass easier. [new add java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg1ji.jpg) [old Add java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6A5y.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With new android studio 4 and above, you can't add the files like the previous way.